# php IntlDateFormatter::formatObject, renders incorrect months

Tags: php, datetime, intl

For some reason i cant make date Formatter to work.

Here is my function:

```
  function renderDate($format, $date)
  {
      $cal = IntlCalendar::fromDateTime($date);
      return IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($cal, $format);
  }
```

Here is the code:

```
      for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
          echo renderDate("MMMM", date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i))) . "<br>";
      }
```

I end up getting :

```
January
March
March
May
May
July
July
August
October
October
December
December
```

This is on Windows 10 using WAMP 5.5.12
Default locale are set to en_Ca, and time zone is correct as well America/Toronto

Comment: So, all the months that are being echoed are those with 31 days. Those that are skipped are those with less. ... Hmm.

Comment: We get this question at the end of every month...but February

Answer (score 0):

You need to put day to mktime function:

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1)
```